# I want to creat a high resolution heat map of a Dataframe with x, y coordinates. data from a football game

Tags: r, heatmap

I have tracked an indoor football game. Every player had a gps tracker which generates every second 20 x-coordinates values and 20 y-coordinates values. So what i want do do is a similar heatmap like in the following image.

What do you think is the easiest and best way?

I have already tried a approach with the MASS package.

```
df <- data.frame(x,y)
h2 <- hist2d(df)
h2 <- hist2d(df, nbins=100, col=r)
h2 <- hist2d(df, nbins=100, col=r, FUN=function(x) log(length(x)))
```

The actual output is a plot on which I can see where my player was and on which position he was more often. But for me the resolution is too low and if I increase the nbins so the dots only getting smaller. For me it should be a little bit like clouds. So what I want is a similar view like in the picture I have mentioned already in the link above.

You can find my dataframe

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SA2oT78wFdXmuz2j2UOOyZvzgwYpgXkT

[image]

Comment: "Easiest and best" is subjective—it's going to depend on your context, skillset, purpose, packages you want to use, etc. Without your data, we can't run your code, and we don't have any of your output. See [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added my data.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `hexbin` package to cluster the points and plot them as a heatmap:

```r
library(hexbin)
library(RColorBrewer)

crbrew <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11,'Spectral')))

hb <- hexbin(df$x,df$y,xbins = 40)

plot(hb, colramp=crbrew)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, interessting approch, but my idea is to have it more like the picture in my question. The heatmap should be like "clouds".